# VB.Net ADODC.RecordSet.EOF not updating

Tags: vb.net, vb6, adodb, recordset, vb6-migration

I'm working on getting a VB6 project through .NET migration after the last guy left. At one point in the program a recordset contained within a ADODC object is looped through (this is done several times with bare ADODB.RecordSet objects and I've gotten those to work) using the standard While Not EOF loop. However I'm finding that when using a RecordSet inside an ADODC object that EOF doesn't update. Here's an example:

```
'VB6.ADODC
adoEchelonMGT.ConnectionString = adoConnectionString()
adoEchelonMGT.RecordSource = "select * from EchelonMGT"
adoEchelonMGT.Refresh()

If (Not adoEchelonMGT.Recordset.EOF And Not adoEchelonMGT.Recordset.BOF And adoEchelonMGT.Recordset.RecordCount > 0) Then
    While Not adoEchelonMGT.Recordset.EOF
        adoEchelonMGT.Recordset.MoveNext()
    End While
End If
```

The code will enter the while loop and never leave. There is only a single record in the record set but EOF will never set to True.

So a final note: Yes I know I should change up my database connections to use full .NET classes, my current orders are "make this work yesterday" (Last guy dragged his feet) so while I know I'm going to have to gut the connection systems at some point in the future, that's not within the scope of what I'm going to do to fix this.

Comment: If there is only one record, then you don't need a while loop.  A simple IF would do.  Also, that first IF block looks unnecessary.

Comment: I won't know how many records there'll be when it's run, in my example there's one, there could be dozens in a production database. The first line is just to deal with some of the usual things that get asked about in these threads (I looked at a few people with similar issues but none of their solutions worked for me).

Comment: Are you doing anything in the loop?  Or just trying to get to the last record?

Comment: In the actual code I'm checking for specific data based on user entry. The code I've provided is a trimmed down example to remove as many variables as possible. The provided code still causes the issue I'm encountering however.

Comment: Think first thing to do is get rid of that IF statement. The While will handle that.

Comment: Do you have an `On Error Resume Next` somewhere above the code you've shown?  Or an `On Error Goto ...` where the error handler executes a `Resume Next` statement?  If the `.EOF` or the `.Movenext` is throwing an error, and you've still got vb6 error handling along those lines, it could be keeping you in the loop, since you'd be ignoring any exceptions.

Comment: @RichardFyffe: maybe is there a Property Window with a BOFAction property? Just asking...

Comment: @deblocker, I think you have the answer, but I also think you mean the EOFAction. If the `ADODC.EOFAction` property is 0 (adDoMoveLast) the recordset is positioned on the last record rather than EOF. If that's the case, then setting the property to 1, (adStayEOF) should be the fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Straight to the point: **Properties Window:**

[image]

**More Details:**

There is a MS reference worth to read: [BOF, EOF Properties (ADO)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/bof-eof-properties-ado) - see the *Remarks* section.

You haven't included in your post the connection string, so please check it out as well, because the correct use of Recordcount, EOF and BOF depends also from the cursor type.

> In some cases RecordCount returns -1 (moreover, sadly,  this may vary depending from the OLEDB Provider), so it is not usable to check for existence of records. The use of the Recordset's RecordCount property requires either the use of:
>
> 1. Static or Keyset server-side cursors
> 2. A client-side cursor

**Why to check simultaneously for EOF and BOF?**

Both true: there are no records, and no current record, every MoveAction will raise a trappable error.

All this means: after you have checked the BOFAction and EOFFAction in the Properties Window, pay also attention how do you check in code for EOF, BOF and Recordcount at the same time.

Comment: That was the issue, the EOF action was move last instead of stay EOF. I changed that and now it works as expected.